# How to re-assign a reference type in another class and have changes stick to original?

Tags: c#, reference, ref

Here is a rather contrived example of what I am asking:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Fruit fruit;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fruit = new Apple();

        Geneticist geneticist = new Geneticist(fruit);

        // Later on in program..

        geneticist.Engineer();

        Console.WriteLine(fruit.Color);

        // Still red because a copy of fruit was made in Geneticist class.
    }
}

class Fruit
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
    public Apple()
    {
        Color = "Red";
    }
}

class Banana : Fruit
{
    public Banana()
    {
        Color = "Yellow";
    }
}

class Geneticist
{
    private Fruit fruit;
    private Banana banana;

    public Geneticist(Fruit fruit)
    {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.banana = new Banana();
    }

    public void Engineer()
    {
        fruit = banana;
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a fruit stored as a member variable in my main form. I want to be able to pass it to my Geneticist class and later on have it re-assign the value.

When I type `fruit = banana;` the fruit in geneticist no longer points to the the Form1 fruit but instead to the local copy in Geneticist. I am looking for a way to simulate the ref keyword, I suppose, where if I re-assign the geneticist fruit the Form1 fruit is also updated with the change.

I suppose I could create a wrapper of fruit and pass that around instead but that seems a bit hackish. Also I could have the `Engineer` method raise an event so that the main form can re-assign the value but having to do that at many parts of my program seems a bit messy as well.

Also, I cannot use the `ref` keyword because I modify it later on, not in the constructor of Geneticist.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The event sounds like a good idea if you don't want to tightly couple Form1 and Geneticist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem with this is that if I re-assign it, it doesn't affect the
>   original in Form1. A copy is made in Geneticist when I type fruit =
>   banana.

**No, this is wrong. No copy is made.**

What happens is that you overwrite the reference you have at hand of the `Apple` with a reference to a `Banana`. It's as if you are given an apple to put in your pocket and after holding on to it for a little while, you leave it on the ground, pick up a banana, and place it in your pocket.

When at some later point you decide to eat the original apple will be intact, *but not because you made a copy*. Only because you just lost interest in it and got hold of a totally unrelated fruit instead.

**So what to do?**

The fact remains that you cannot modify the `Fruit` parameter as a whole with reference semantics (the CLR does not allow refs to be stored as class members, as you yourself have said).

If you want `Geneticist` to modify the `Fruit` reference, then you do have to create a wrapper around it. But the most practical solution would be to have the calling code cooperate with `Geneticist`:

```
class Geneticist
{
    private Fruit fruit;
    private Banana banana;

    public Geneticist(Fruit fruit)
    {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.banana = new Banana();
    }

    public Fruit Engineer()
    {
        fruit = banana;
        return fruit; // return the new value
    }
}
```

And the calling code:

```
fruit = new Apple();

Geneticist geneticist = new Geneticist(fruit);
fruit = geneticist.Engineer(); // use the return value this way
Console.WriteLine(fruit.Color);
```

**Another workable approach**

What about letting the `Geneticist` know how to modify the fruit themselves?

```
class Geneticist
{
    private Fruit fruit;

    private readonly Banana banana;

    private readonly Action<Fruit> engineer;

    public Geneticist(Fruit fruit, Action<Fruit> engineer)
    {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.banana = new Banana();
        this.engineer = engineer;
    }

    public void Engineer()
    {
        this.engineer(this.banana);
    }
}
```

And the calling code:

```
Fruit fruit = new Apple();
Geneticist geneticist = new Geneticist(fruit, f => { fruit = f; });
geneticist.Engineer();
Console.WriteLine(fruit.Color);
```

Comment: Er, yeah, I know. I apologize for not wording that properly. I'll fix it in the original post.

Comment: @KylePrice: Finished editing. Maybe a not so pure but much more practical approach would be acceptable?

Comment: Jon: That is the approach I am using right now in parts of the program. However, the problem is that sometimes I cannot return `fruit` because the function may not end there or the caller is not the main form.

Comment: @KylePrice: Updated with another approach, check it out. In essence this is the wrapper approach, only with the wrapper being helpfully generated by the compiler at no hassle to you.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it might work! Thanks for all your help.